# xcode 4.5, iOS 6.0 SDK Compile error - base.h

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, llvm-gcc, ios6

I upgraded from xcode 4.4.3 to 4.5 and can no longer build our application. I receive the following compile error in iOS 6.0 SDK base.h:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/base.h:103:44: error: missing binary operator before token "("

I immediately tried to revert back to iOS 5.1.1 SDK and found I could not. I went to Xcode->preferences->downloads but no previous SDK versions are available to install.. only simulators and command-line tools.

One of our developers discovered that reverting from LLVM GCC 4.2 to Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 resolved the compile issue..

But seems I must download the previous version of xcode 4.4.3 to get iOS 5.1.1 SDK.

Does anyone have iOS 5.1.1 sdk installed under xcode 4.5?

Has anyone experienced iOS 6.0 SDK build issues?

Thanks...

Comment: same problem here compiling a javascript LIB. Did you fix it?
The problem does not appear when im compiling for debug :S

Answer (score 1):

I experienced same error with LLVM GCC 4.2.

base.h is included by dispatch/dispatch.h and I needed to change file that include  .
I found that the source file should be Objective C (or C++) file. Not C (or C++) file.

Two solutions.
1. Change file extension from cpp to m or mm.
2. Change File Type to "Objective C" or "Objective C++" of Identity and Type of Utility area of XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that when I'm building apps on SDK 6.0 some of my view controllers are showing only o half of a screen. It does not matter if device has iOS 5 or 6 installed. Seems that issue is caused by the SDK used to build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having all manner of problems going from 4.3.2 IOS5.1 to 4.5 IOS6.0. Nightmare.

See my post:

[IOS 6.0 xcode 4.5 compilation errors #import code held in files outside of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609963/ios-6-0-xcode-4-5-compilation-errors-import-code-held-in-files-outside-of-the-c#comment16999364_12609963)

When I get into work tomorrow, I'm going to remove all the frameworks, re-add them.

Additionally, check Github to see if some of my third party objects have build updates for IOS6.