# IOS 6.0 xcode 4.5 compilation errors #import code held in files outside of the class

Tags: objective-c, import, xcode4.5

I've been happily compiling and going my merry way with Xcode 4.3.2 (IOS5.1). Now that I've taken the plunge and decided to move to Xcode 4.5 my App fails compilation in a most miserable manner. Now, I've not got past the issue with ARMV7 or anything like that yet. No. My issue is probably going to make many of you groan.

But you can blame my basic ANSI C days for that. Everyone likes reusable code and I've created lots of it. BUT!!! I've not made any of this particular code into object(s) per se. That is, I've not taken the steps of the Interface and Implementation to heart.

Sure, I have my classes for my view controllers etc. But, to save having to **declare** and **alloc** **init** objects so I can use the methods therein, I've simply dumped a load of methods into a .inc file - in other words an include file. E.g, I'd have a method for altering the background colour or background image a of a table cell - and I'd import the file that had the method that did it.

E.g.

```
-(void)defaultInactiveBackGroundForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {

   cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:DEFAULT_INACT_CELL_BACKGROUND_IMAGE] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

} // defaultInactiveBackGroundForCell
```

All well and good so far.

And, I'd #import the file (containing the above code) at the top of my class file, my .m file. In my willDisplayCell delegate method, i'd simply call the following method:

```
[self defaultInactiveBackGroundForCell:cell];
```

And it'd work.

But under Xcode 4.5 it's kicking off big time:

Missing contact for method in declaration.

So, my question is: Is there any way at all of #importing code into a class .m fill like we used to do in the old days with ANSI C?

Help ?

Comment: Did you try using #include instead of #import?

Comment: Yes I did. That was the first thing I thought of. I'm utterly flummoxed. I cannot figure it. At the end of the day, method code either imported or included within the implementation @end should be ok. But it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem might be. The methods that I'm importing are fully implemented, that is, they're not headers. These full methods are #imported after my @implementation line.

I added the method spec, in the form of a .h file as a private class inbetween my @interface and my @end as part of a private method declaration within the @implementation.

I'm perhaps not making sense but essentially, Xcode 4.3.2 seemed to be happy to have all of these methods import in between the @implementation and @end. But Xcode 4.5 utterly does not. It requires the headers defined too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's related to your 'Object Orientation' or lack there of. As of Xcode 4.5, the minimum deployment target is iOS 4.3. I had a header import error on a recent project after migrating to Xcode 4.5 where my deployment target was 4.0. Changing that to 4.3 fixed it.

Comment: Hmm - I've checked that at it was actually set to 5.1. Setting it to 6.0 causes similar errors. The error appears to be indicating that the cod that's being imported should have a corresponding header in the interface, hence the huge amount of "missing context in method declaration" errors. Setting it to 4.3 removes all of those errors but causes errors indicative of ARC weak references?

Comment: Has no one got anything further to add here? I'm literally clutching at straws?